# How can I draw a semi transparent coloured mask over an already drawn to SWT canvas?

Tags: java, drawing, swt, java-canvas

so I'd like to draw a coloured (red) area over the top of an existing canvas drawing, like a red tinted lens being placed over it, so the original image is still visible underneath.

The problem is that I am extending a canvas that draws it's own image and I am drawing over the top of it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Canvas paint()` method,

1. draw image
2. `gc.setAlpha(100)` //decide your value
3. `gc.fillRectangle(rect)` //rect is client area of the canvas

I believe you should get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The naive solution is to add a `SWT.Paint` event listener to the `Canvas`, as that can run into problems as we don't know the sequence of calls to listeners (have a look at `EventTable.hook()` which will reuse an old slot in the listener table before adding to the end of the table...). Thus the original listener might run before or after your listener.

A better solution - which I have not tried, but believe to work - whould be to add a new `Composite` on top of the original `Canvas` and then add your listener to this widget, as any `Paint` listener of the new `Composite` is guaranteed to run after all listeners on the `Canvas`itself. Remember to

- add a `Size` listener to the `Canvas` to make sure the size of the `Composite` is always correct
- use `setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE)` on the `Canvas`

Answer (score -1):

setting the alpha value to a canvas only dims the color and does not make it transparent. Actual transparent gui in possible only with shell by using shell.setAlpha(x);

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't the case. The Alpha drawing over an existing image did indeed produce transparency.